# Email validation access to database denied

Tags: php, forms, validation, email

I am trying to input an email validation form but am finding it impossible.

The latest obstacle to be thrown at me is:

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'registrations'.

This error comes up before any data is inputted into the forms. I am using WAMPserver for the site and don't know why this error is occurring.

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "username") or die(mysql_error()); // Connect to database server(localhost) with username and password.  
mysql_select_db("registrations") or die(mysql_error()); // Select registrations database.
```

When i put in a password in with my username and local host the error states :

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost'(using password YES) to database 'registrations'.

Does anyone know what would be causing this problem? I have a feeling it's something small but i just can't figure it out.

Comment: @localhost is the server name, not the username or an email. It is saying access is denied for the user at server localhost. You probably just need to grant select/insert/update to the user on that database.

Comment: I'm going to assume you are passing the password in the connection string and simply omitted it from your post here, correct? If not, you'll need to supply the password as well as follow @JonathanKuhn's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

it means user 'localhost' doesn't have privileges to access database 'registrations'. you will need to grant privileges to user 'localhost' for database 'registrations'. check out this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html) .hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your error it seems like there is no username being passed, and i don't see a password either

Example:

```
$host = "localhost";
$username = "your username";
$password = "your password";
$databasename = "your db name";

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($databasename);
```

This should work